# existence of a complementary subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a general vector space  $V$ (could be possible uncountably infinite dimensional) and a list of vectors $(e_s)_{s \in S}$ that is linearly independent but doesn't span the whole of $V$. Is it true that I will always have a subspace $U \subset V$ such that $V= \langle e_s \rangle_{s \in S} \oplus U$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, extend $\{e_s\}_{s\in S}$ to a basis of $V$, call it $B$. Letting $U =B \setminus\{e_s\}$ gives a complementary subspace. so that $V = \langle e_s\rangle _{s\in S}\oplus \langle U\rangle $

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can always complete your linearly independent set to a basis, say $(e_s)_{s\in S}\cup(f_t)_{t\in T}$, and take $W=\text{span}\,\{f_t\}_{t\in T}$.

Comment: The worst obstacle might be that the Axiom of Choice might be used.

Comment: Hard to do much about infinite-dimensional spaces without it ;)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. This is to do with the existence of the Hamel basis which uses Zorn's lemma which is equivalent to the axiom of choice, right?

Comment: Indeed.${\ \ \ \  }$